# LINQ - I need to pull records from table 2 based on values in table 1

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have `2 tables`, `table 1` has a field which contains `prefixes` for companies.

The values retrieved from table 1 need to be used to get records from table 2 (based on the prefixes returned).

I coded below to do a startswith to demo what I need done, however what I need to do is build a dynamic starswith clause.

I know the code below wont compile, just putting it out there to show what I would like to accomplish.

```
//*   This pulls list of prefixes from Table 1

var xrfPrefixes = from xx in XrfPrefixes
 select new
 {
   xxx.CompanyPrefix
 };

//* Get list of prefixes
string PrefixList = "";
foreach (var xxx in xrfJobPrefix)
{
    PrefixList = PrefixList + xxx.FirmJobPrefix + ",";
}

//* Get back Matching records from table 2
var results = from p in Orders.Where(p => p.OrdCust.StartsWith(PrefixList))
select p;
```

Sample Data in Table 1 (Customers):

- Row 1: Customer_Prefix char(50) value = "ab1, ab2"
- Row 2: Customer_Prefix char(50) value = "xy1"
- Row 3: Customer_Prefix char(50) value = "xy2"

Sample data in table 2 (orders):

- row 1: customer_name char(50) value = "ab1filler"
- row 2: customer_name char(50) value = "ab2filler"
- row 3: customer_name char(50) value = "ab3filler"
- row 4: customer_name char(50) value = "xy1filler"
- row 5: customer_name char(50) value = "xy2filler"
- row 6: customer_name char(50) value = "xy3filler"

Based on the customer_prefixes in the Customers table, the records from Orders Table returned would be Rows 1,2,4 & 5

Comment: Your code has confused me... it would be more useful if you could show some sample data and what you would expect the result to be.

Comment: or at least the plain T-SQL that you would do to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a PrefixList. Don't do it as a list of comma-separated strings, do it as a real `List<String>`. That means you have to split comma-separated values (using `String.Split`, for example):

   ```
   var prefixList = new List<string>();
   foreach (var xxx in xrfJobPrefix) 
   { 
       prefixList.AddRange(xxx.FirmJobPrefix.Split(',').Select(pre => pre.Trim())); 
   }
   ```
2. After you have a PrefixList, you can do a simple LINQ query as follows:

   ```
   var results = from p in orders
                 from pre in prefixList
                 where p.OrdCust.StartsWith(pre)) 
                 select p;
   ```

Comment: This executed fine however if I put in: results.Dump(); I receive the error: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.. researching this error now.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
        var items = from o in Orders
                    where (
                        from pf in XrfPrefixes
                        where o.OrdCust.StartsWith(pf.CompanyPrefix)
                        select pf).Any()
                    select o;
```